# Support for require("module-name") in html with webpack bundles

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I have an existing site, using requirejs that started off with

```
<head>
<script src="/assets/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/config.js"></script><!-- the requirejs config -->
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script><!-- concats all defines from modules/*.js -->
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    require("modules/header", function(header) {
      header.init(); //sets up event hooks for navigation, and search bar
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

So now I get a good webpack bundle created.

But now the `require` statements embedded throughout our html fails because the `require` function is undefined

How does one get webpack to emit its AMD require function as window.require so that this all still works again, without major rewrites all over this 300 pages of CMS published app?